# Jenkins specify a not case with an expression?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want a Jenkins stage to execute when it isn't the `master` branch and when a certain parameter is set. I'm doing this:

```
stage('Deploy') {
      when {
        allOf {
            expression { return params.ACTION == "create" };
            not {
                anyOf {
                    expression { branch 'master' }
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

But when I run the Jenkins job, this stage is skipped altogether. Something is wrong with the syntax I think but not sure what.

Comment: Why do you have `anyOf` in your logical?

Comment: I guess it's not needed. It's a leftover piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
stage('Deploy'){
        when {
            expression { return (params.ACTION == "create" && env.BRANCH_NAME !='master')};
        }

    }
```